# Invoking static method dynamically in powershell

Tags: powershell, static, metaprogramming

I would like to invoke a static method from an object based on the class of that object. For example, assume that you have the following class structure with static methods.

```
Class Super {
    static [string] getX() {
        return "X"
    }
}

Class Sub1 : Super {
    static [string] getX() {
        return "Sub1X"
    }

}
Class Sub2 : Super {
    static [string] getX() {
        return "Sub2X"
    }

}


$someSubclass = [Sub1]::new()

#I would like to invoke getX() from this instances classes static method.
$result = $someSubclass.GetType().getX()  #This (of course) does not work.
```

In this snippet above, I would like $result to contain the string "Sub1X". 
Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as any other static member - use the `::` [static member operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#static-member-operator-):

```
$someSubClass = [Sub1]::new()
$result = $someSubClass::getX()
```

Comment: @Hutch It's always easier _once you know_ ^_^ hindsight is 20/20